# A singular algebraic variety is not a smooth manifold, but is it the union of a finite number of smooth manifolds?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry, real-algebraic-geometry

I have the solution set of a collection of homogenous polynomials with coefficients in $\mathbb{R}$, which is a projective variety. In general projective varieties are not smooth, they may have singularities, self intersections such as the system where $x=(x_1,x_2,x_3)$ satisfies $x_1x_2=0$ in $\mathbb{R}P^2$. However is it always the case that we can view a projective variety as a finite union of smooth manifolds embedded in projective space? It seems intuitively true to me but I'm neither a geometer or algebraist so I don't have the tools or the references to figure this out for myself.

Comment: The singular locus is itself a projective variety of strictly smaller dimension, and so the same is true for the singular locus of the singular locus etc. Hence you have a finite stratification by smooth (quasi-projective) varieties.

Comment: There is no hope in general to write a projective variety as a finite union of smooth, *projective*  varieties. For instance, the cuspidal curve $$\{x_0x_1^2-x_2^3=0\} \subset \mathbb{P}^2$$
is singular, but irreducible.

Comment: Ah okay. It is the union of the manifolds $\{x=z=0\}$, $\{y=z=0\}$, and $\{x=\frac{z^3}{y^2},y,z\neq 0\}$ though, so are you implying it can be done if the manifolds/varieties are embedded in Euclidean space?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudomanifold

Comment: Depending on what you mean by singular locus, Polizzi's comment is an answer.  Your definition would allow non-reduced varieties, which seems inevitable, but leads to complications.  For example if $X = V(F^2) $, then there are no smooth points. In the case of the cuspidal cubic, $C = V(x^2- y^3) $ we have $Sing(C) = V(x,y^2,x^2- y^3) = V(x,y^2) $, so the singular locus is the origin, which is non-singular, but with multiplicity 2. If you allow the property of taking the reduced singular set, you win though.

Comment: The elliptic conus $x_1^2+x_2^2-x_3^2=0$ in $\mathbb{P}^3_{\mathbb{R}}$ is irreducible and singular in $[1:0:0:0]$.

Comment: @aginensky $V(x_0x_1^2-x_2^3)$ is not smooth by Jacobian criterion, and because $\mathbb{R}$ is a perfect field, this is equivalent to singularity of it.

Comment: @Armando.  That was my point.  However, it is simply a non-reduced point, so it is smooth with the reduced scheme structure.